# accessing the spring-restdocs generated content in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I'm using Spring Restdocs (v1.1.2) in a Spring Boot (v1.4.1) application.

In the jar task of the Gradle build file, I'm copying the generated output into public/docs:

```
jar {
  dependsOn asciidoctor
  from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
    into 'public/docs'
  }
}
```

and I see in the generated JAR the document in

```
BOOT-INF/classes/public/docs/api-guide.html
```

However, when I run the JAR, I can't seem to address the api-guide.html at /docs, /public/docs, etc.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

--john

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.asciidoctor.convert" version "1.5.3"
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

ext {
    snippetsDir = file('build/generated-snippets')
    springRestdocsVersion = '1.1.2.RELEASE'
}


test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

asciidoctor {
    attributes 'snippets': snippetsDir
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}

jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'public/docs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    testCompile("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:${springRestdocsVersion}")
}
```

=============================================================

here's the application config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableScheduling
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run Application, args
    }
}
```

and the test config:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application)
class ApplicationTests {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information about how you've configured your Boot app?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Andy. It's a pretty standard Gradle build for spring boot, but I've included more of the build.gradle above.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I was more interested in your app's configuration. For example, if you'd used `@EnableWebMvc` which disables Boot's default support for serving static resources.

Comment: I understand and have added the application and test config annotations above.

Comment: That all looks ok. What's logged when you start your application?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I had the spring-boot-actuator-docs enabled:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
```

and it was "taking over" the /docs path.  As soon as I relocated the generated restdocs to a different path, e.g.

```
jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/api'
    }
}
```

all was good.

Thanks Andy for your interest in my question and the very cool Spring REST Docs project!